# Converting XML dataset issue

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file something like this

```
  <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
    <SharePointFormDataResponse xmlns =""http:///"">
      <CustomerName>xyz</CustomerName>
      <PMTREV2012>
        <Transaction>
         <Title>Full payment</Title>
         <Amount>321323231</Amount>
         <Month>Feb</Month>
         <Year>2017</Year>
       </Transaction>
       <Transaction>
         <Title>Full payment</Title>
         <Amount>321323231</Amount>
         <Month>Feb</Month>
         <Year>2017</Year>
       </Transaction>
     </PMTREV2012>
     <INTREV2012>
       <Transaction>
         <TransactionType>Full payment</TransactionType>
         <Amount>321323231</Amount>
         <Month>Feb</Month>
         <Year>2017</Year>
       </Transaction>
       <Transaction>
         <TransactionType>Full payment</TransactionType>
         <Amount>321323231</Amount>
         <Month>Feb</Month>
         <Year>2017</Year>
       </Transaction>
     </INTREV2012>
   </SharePointFormDataResponse>
```

and I am converting this XML to dataset using following code

```
XmlNodeReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(altitudeResponse);
dsAltitude.ReadXml(xmlReader);
```

when I execute this all the transaction node will be merged into one data table. But I want them to be in a different table based on the parent node. I there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Not really.  The data is in a different column.  You can either separate the table after it is loaded or manually parse the xml file into a table.   Both are pretty simple to do.

Comment: What is "altitudeResponse" and what is the expected output?

Comment: Altitude response is xml string

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

XmlNodeReader accepts `XmlNode` as constructor argument. Just pass corresponding parent nodes to each table you are filling:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(altitudeResponse);
var parents = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>()
                 .Where(n => n.Name != "CustomerName");

foreach(var parentNode in parents)
{
    using (XmlNodeReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(parentNode))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
        dt.TableName = parentNode.Name;
        dsAltitude.Tables.Add(dt);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately without schema you cannot read data directly into DataTable - you should use DataSet for that.

Output - DataSet with two DataTables:

```
{
  "PMTREV2012": [
    {
      "Title": "Full payment",
      "Amount": "321323231",
      "Month": "Feb",
      "Year": "2017"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Full payment",
      "Amount": "321323231",
      "Month": "Feb",
      "Year": "2017"
    }
  ],
  "INTREV2012": [
    {
      "TransactionType": "Full payment",
      "Amount": "321323231",
      "Month": "Feb",
      "Year": "2017"
    },
    {
      "TransactionType": "Full payment",
      "Amount": "321323231",
      "Month": "Feb",
      "Year": "2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error called "Cannot find table 0."

Comment: @KeerthiKumar I don't have any errors with xml you provided. Is your real xml different? I modified query slightly to skip all customer name nodes if you have several

Comment: @Sergery. I am sorry. your code is working fine. thanks a lot. I need to modify it slightly. I have two more extra nodes with the customer name. like<CustomerName>Keerthi Kumar</CustomerName<CIF>123456789</CIF><CardFirst4>4543</CardFirst4><CardLast4>5434</CardLast4> these things should be placed in other table. could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

This one is little bulky, but will produce the required output

```
 public static void ReadXMLResponse()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\\Response.xml");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("INTREV2012");

        dt.Columns.Add("col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Amount");
        dt.Columns.Add("Month");
        dt.Columns.Add("Year");

        dt = doc.Descendants("INTREV2012").Descendants("Transaction")
                  .Select(x =>
                  {
                      var row = dt.NewRow();
                      row.SetField<string>("col1", (string)x.Element("TransactionType").Value);
                      row.SetField<string>("Amount", (string)x.Element("Amount").Value);
                      row.SetField<string>("Month", (string)x.Element("Month").Value);
                      row.SetField<string>("Year", (string)x.Element("Year").Value);
                      return row;
                  }).CopyToDataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        dt = new System.Data.DataTable("PMTREV2012");

        dt.Columns.Add("col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Amount");
        dt.Columns.Add("Month");
        dt.Columns.Add("Year");

        dt = doc.Descendants("PMTREV2012").Descendants("Transaction")
                  .Select(x =>
                  {
                      var row = dt.NewRow();
                      row.SetField<string>("col1", (string)x.Element("Title").Value);
                      row.SetField<string>("Amount", (string)x.Element("Amount").Value);
                      row.SetField<string>("Month", (string)x.Element("Month").Value);
                      row.SetField<string>("Year", (string)x.Element("Year").Value);
                      return row;
                  }).CopyToDataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables.Count);
    }
```

Comment: Or you can opt to use the conventional method to loop through elements and create tables. So, search for parent elements, create a table and use Sergey's method for current element.

Comment: How to get a particular node and convert it to data table.. i want to do this for parent node